# Flex FileReference: Open Dialog at a default location

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I set FileRefernce to open browse at a default location? If the default location is at C:/test then I always want to open browse from C:/test.

Comment: I didn't think this was possible; it is operating system specific.  I retagged this post; as this has nothing to do w/ Flex or Flash Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in pure AS3.0, no way, because that's not possible due to Flash Security Sandbox.

but, if you are using a Air `File` Class. it's possible.

in Adobe Forum, same issue question here: [FileReference set directory?](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/856695)

[File_Class Adobe Documents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)

> File.applicationStorageDirectory—a storage directory unique to each
>   installed AIR application
>
> File.applicationDirectory—the read-only
>   directory where the application is installed (along with any installed
>   assets)
>
> File.desktopDirectory—the user's desktop directory
>
> File.documentsDirectory—the user's documents directory
>
> File.userDirectory—the user directory